# How to perform a matrix multiplicaton on ruby?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, matrix, matrix-multiplication

Hi everyone in my Programming Paradigms class we just started to learn how to program in ruby. One exercise asks to implement a function that multiplyes two matrices.

Using normally java I tried thinking making three bidimensional arrays and this is how I tries to implement it for two matrices 2x2:

```
def matrixmultiplicator(first_matrix, second_matrix)
    result_matrix = [][]
    first_matrix.each_index do |i|
        second_matrix[i].each_index do |j|
            sum = 0
            //This loop range is just a test for two 2x2 matrices
            (0..1).each do |k|
                sum = sum +(first_matrix[i][j+k] * second_matrix[j+k][i])
            end
        result_matrix[i][j] = sum
        end
    end
end

matrixmultiplicator([[1, 2], [3, 4]], [[2, 3], [3, 3]])
```

unfortunately I recive this error:
wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1..2) (ArgumentError)

Could someone help me?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Check this: https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-2A

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't do what you think it does:

```
result_matrix = [][]
```

That's trying to call the "array indexing method" (`[]`) on an empty array but doesn't pass any argument to the `[]` method. Operators are just methods with some syntactic sugar in Ruby so `[][]` is roughly equivalent to:

```
empty_array = []
empty_array.[]()
```

where `.[]` is a call to the `[]` method (just like `obj.m` is a call to the `m` method) and `()` is an empty argument list.

Ruby (like most languages) doesn't have multi-dimensional arrays, it has arrays-of-arrays so you could create the inner arrays the first time you need them:

```
result_matrix = [ ]
#...
result_matrix[i]  ||= [ ]
result_matrix[i][j] = sum
```

instead of

```
result_matrix[i][j] = sum
```

Or you could prefill `result_matrix`:

```
result_matrix = Array.new(2) { [ ] }
```

See the [Array constructor docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-c-new) to see what's going on with that `Array.new` call.